# Как правильно использовать GetPathFromToken

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, media-library

Работаю с Windows Phone 8. Нужно получить путь к аудио файлу. Для изображения это делается просто.

```
PictureCollection pictures = library.Pictures;
Picture singlePict = pictures[index];
path = singlePict.GetPath().ToString();
```

А вот для аудио такой функции нет. Поэтому пытаюсь использовать библиотеку MediaLibraryExtensions. И там есть метод GetPathFromToken, который позволяет получить путь к медиа файлу. Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом:

```
SongCollection songs = library.Songs;
Song singleSong = songs[index];
name = singleSong.Name;
path = library.GetPathFromToken(name);
```

Но ничего не выходит. Если кто знает, подскажите, что нужно передать в параметр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Token` -- это значение, идентифицирующее конкретный файл, которое вы получаете, если пользователь выбрал команду `Share` или `Edit` для медиаэлемента (картинка, песня и т.д.), а ваше приложение умеет обрабатывать эти команды (см. Extensions в манифесте приложения), либо если пользователь открывает файл, а ваше приложение умеет обрабатывать этот тип файла. Значение токена -- это обычный GUID, которому ОС сопоставляет конкретный файл по конкретному пути.

Так что в вашем примере вы не сможете получить путь к файлу.